# mirror a site with wget and download static media

Tags: wget

I'd like to mirror a site with wget and convert all the links to the local copies I've downloaded.  So far that's easy all I have to do is `wget -mk http://site.com`

However all of the static media is located in a different domain, if I follow all of the foreign hosts using the `-H` option it will download that static media files, but it will also download anything else externally linked.

Is there a way to specify 'only download foreign hosts specified in list X'?

Answer (score 2):

Add -Dwww.domain.com,static.domain.com with your equivalent domains.

Answer (score 1):

See the section in the wget manpage after the  `--page-requisites` option, it has an example:

> Links from that page to external documents will not be followed.  Actually, to download a single page and all its requisites (even if they exist on separate websites), and make sure the lot displays properly locally, this author likes to use a few options in addition to -p:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p http://<site>/<document>
```

Comment: I tried the `-p` option, but still no luck

Comment: should I take that to mean that you tried the -p option but ignored the section I quoted that tells you that you need a few more options and gives you an example?

Comment: exactly, I'm already using `-k`.  `-K` does nothing more but backup files before converting them and `-E` just renames extensions if needed.

As for `-H`, you can see my problem with that in my initial question.